# Who is logged in at DISPLAY :0

Tags: x11

Is there a way to find out who is logged in to X on the *console*?

In Ubuntu 16.04 I can use `who` which tells you where you are located, like in this example where `test1`: is logged in at the *X-console* while I am logged in with `ssh`.

```
$ who
test1    tty7         2017-08-12 02:00 (:0)
ulf      pts/1        2017-08-16 13:56 (192.168.1.20)
```

But on both Debian 4.0 and OpenBSD 5.1 `who` will not tell me this and the output is slightly different.

Is there a stable way that will work on most systems to get hold of the user who is logged in at the *X-console*?

Comment: This looks more like a system administration question than a programming question.

Comment: Posted it to serverfault: https://serverfault.com/q/869125/243665

Answer (score 0):

The FROM field can be displayed on most systems with `w -f`.

Comment: The man page say `The default as released is for the  from  field  to  not  be printed, although your system administrator or distribution maintainer may have compiled a version in which the from field is shown by default.` and in the Ubuntu and Debian releases its already on and in OpenBSD its on and tells me `-f ... no longer supported`. But `w` does not help me anyway I think.

Comment: What about `last -f /var/log/utmp`?

Answer (score 0):

`logname` may serve your needs. It shows the originally logged in user, even after `su`. See [POSIX: logname](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/logname.html).

> The logname utility shall write the user's login name to standard output. The login name shall be the string that would be returned by the getlogin() function defined in the System Interfaces volume of POSIX.1-2008. Under the conditions where the getlogin() function would fail, the logname utility shall write a diagnostic message to standard error and exit with a non-zero exit status.

I found some terminal emulators fail to give the right feedback, for example gnome-terminal in Ubuntu 16.04. I'm not sure if it is a bug of Ubuntu or just that version of gnome-terminal; gnome-terminal on fedora and debian does not have the issue.

There has been discussions that `logname` may be faked by evil applications, but I do not find the link again, I think it was a gnome-devel discussion.

Comment: Not the thing I'm looking for! If the user `bert` sits down in front of computer `foo` and logs in he is at the _X-console_ (or whatever it is called). When I at the same time log in with `ssh` to `foo`,  `logname` will tell `ulf` while I would like to get `bert`.